# How to increase jQuery value based on .each

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imgtlist').each(function(index) {
        $('#slide_box').attr('width', + 135);
    });
});
```

Essentialy, on load, count the number of nodes with class `.imgtlist` and add 135 to the width attribute of `#slide_box`.

Do I need to define a var for the each loop and then increase based on the number of `.imgtlist`?

Comment: Why are you looping? It doesn't seem necessary unless you're planning to add 135 to the slide box for each image in .imglist)

Comment: Why do you use .each?? `$('#slide_box').attr('width', + 135});` outside each would be the same though

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do exactly.  Increase `#slide_box` width by 135 * (number of imgtlist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#slide_box").width($("#slide_box").width() + 135 * $(".imgtlist").length);
```

This increases `#slide_box`'s width by 135 * the number of `.imgtlist` elements.

Comment: Did not know `.length` existed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do it without iterating through the children elements.

You can also use the `width()` method of your parent element, so that you don't have to search for the width attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slide_box').width($('.imgtlist').length * 135);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need the each statement. Why not try

```
var number = $('.imgtlist').length * 135;

$('#slide_box').attr('width', number);
```

This gets you the number of items and times it by 135 which would have been your number in the eachstatement. Then you only apply the attr once.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a function as parameter it gets the old `width` as argument.

```
$('#slide_box').width(function(i, width) {
    return width+ 135 * $(".imgtlist").length;
});
```